# How to calculate the visible percentage of a composable item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use Compose as a item in RecyclerView, I want to calculate the visible percentage of item. But the `boundsInParent` and `boundsInRoot` doesn't change when scroll up and down, the visible area is same as item size.

The following is code, this code works well when use in `LazyColumn`

````
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    
                    val bounds = it.boundsInParent()

                    val visibleArea = bounds.height * bounds.width
                    val totalArea = it.size.width * it.size.height
                    val percentage =  visibleArea / totalArea
                    L.d("TAG", "In recyclerview: $percentage, ${it.boundsInWindow()}, ${it.boundsInParent()}, ${it.boundsInRoot()}")
                }
        )```
````

Comment: It is not related to the question, but with a `LazyColumn` is better to use `layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` instead of the `onGloballyPositioned` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use compose in RecyclerView, you should also use `View` to calculate the visibility percentage, the following code works!

```
fun Modifier.visibilityPercentage(callback: (Float) -> Unit): Modifier {
    return composed {
        val view = LocalView.current.parent as View
        onGloballyPositioned {
            callback(visibilityPercentage(view))
        }
    }
}

private fun visibilityPercentage(view: View): Float {
    if (!view.isAttachedToWindow) return 0f
    val rect = Rect()
    if (!view.getLocalVisibleRect(rect)) return 0f
    val totalArea = (view.height * view.width).toFloat()
    if (totalArea == 0f) return 0f
    val visibleArea(rect.bottom - rect.top) * (rect.right - rect.left)
    return visibleArea / totalArea
}
```